# How to import excel data into database using PHP excel library

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to import excel data into database using PHP excel Library .It is working for small amount of data .For large data (30000 rows) it is not working .It is taking much time .
here is my code

```
$fileName = $_FILES["production"]["tmp_name"];
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
$phpspreadsheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
                 
                $total_data = $phpspreadsheet->getHighestRow();
                     //echo $chunkSize;
                    // exit;
                $highest_column = $phpspreadsheet->getHighestColumn();
for ($row = 2 ; $row <= $total_data; $row++) {
                   $productionDataAll = $phpspreadsheet-> rangeToArray ('A' . $row . ':' . $highest_column . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
                        
                         $line=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][0]);
                         $workedorder=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][1]);
                         $modelnumber=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][2]);
                         $revision=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][3]);
                         if(!empty($productionDataAll[0][4])){
                         $serialnumber=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][4]);
                         }
                         else{
                           $serialnumber='';
                         }
                         $lpn=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][5]);
                         $shift=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][6]);
                         $datecreated=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][7]);
                         $datecompleted=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][8]);
                         $repairflag=htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][9]);
                         $date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
                         $skeydate=date("Ymd", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
                           $skey=$skeydate.$line;
  $importproduction=importproduction($mysql_connectionLinkLocal,$line,$workedorder,$modelnumber,$revision,$serialnumber,$lpn,$shift,$repairflag,$date,$skey,$datecreated,$datecompleted); // insert function
            
                  }
```

above code is reading sheet data one by one and inserting into database. How to read the sheet data by 100 (chunck)?
How to reduce the loading time ?I am getting page unresponsive

Comment: For your use case, you might want to look into https://github.com/box/spout.

Comment: I have put below lines. but it is taking 6 minutes 
  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
 ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
 ini_set('max_input_time', -1);